# How to make my code output more decimal places

Tags: java

I have an homework assignment to:
Write a program to calculate the result of one of three operations (minimum, L1 norm, L2 norm) on a vector of three numbers.
All my code is right, I think, but I need my outputs to have 2 decimal places. How would I do this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class LA3a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter three numbers: ");
        double a = sc.nextDouble();
        double b = sc.nextDouble();
        double c = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter operation: ");
        String opr = sc.next();

        if (opr.equals("min")) {
            System.out.print("min(" , a , ", " , b , ", " , c , ")=");
            if (a < b) {
                if (a < c) {
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println();
                }

                else {
                    System.out.print(c);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }

            else {
                if (b < c) {
                    System.out.print(b);
                    System.out.println();
                }

                else {
                    System.out.print(c);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        else if (opr.equals("l1")) {
            double sum = Math.abs(a) + Math.abs(b) + Math.abs(c);
            System.out.println("l1(" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")=" + sum);
        }

        else if (opr.equals("l2")) {
            double sum = a * a + b * b + c * c;
            System.out.println("l2(" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")=" + String.format("%.2f", Math.sqrt(sum)));
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid operation!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `printf` to have a formatted print of a decimal number with 2 decimal places.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", b);
```

the `%.2f` syntax tells Java to return your variable **`(b)`** with 2 decimal places. if you want more decimal places just increase it like: `%.3f` for 3 decimal places or `%.4f` for 4 decimal places.

Comment: It's still only giving me one decimal place.

Comment: pleae write completely your question with its output in question section.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code to:

```
         if (a < b) {

            if (a < c) {

                System.out.printf("%.2f", a);

                System.out.println();

            }

            else {

                System.out.printf("%.2f", c);

                System.out.println();

            }

        }

        else {

            if (b < c) {

                System.out.printf("%.2f", b);
                System.out.println();

            }

            else {

                System.out.printf("%.2f", c);

                System.out.println();

            }

        }

    }
```

and my output is still only coming out as:
Enter three numbers: 1 2 3
Enter operation: min
min(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) = 1.00 - I still need this line to come out with 2 decimal places for each number.

Answer (score 0):

For this part, there is an error:

```
System.out.print("min(" , a , ", " , b , ", " , c , ")=");
```

You put a bunch of commas instead of addition operators, your code should look like this:

```
System.out.print("min(" + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ")=");
```

Also you have a common print statement in the following if/else statement:

```
if (a < c) {

            System.out.print(a);

            System.out.println();

        }

        else {

            System.out.print(c);

            System.out.println();

        }
```

You should extract the print statement and use a call to Math.min() instead of an if statement to make it look something like this:

```
System.out.print(Math.min(a, c));
System.out.println();
```

As for having your output display two decimal places, Java has a class called DecimalFormat which can be imported with java.text.DecimalFormat; Create a new DecimalFormat like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); //#0.00 means that we have two zeros after the decimal place
```

This makes a new DecimalFormat object that we can use to convert our numbers to Strings. For example, your print statement for the l1 operation should look something like this:

```
System.out.println("l1(" + df.format(a) + ", " + df.format(b) + ", " + df.format(c) + ")=" + df.format(sum));
```